# Concatenating multiple rows with similar names in R

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I have a dataframe db1 with say 30 variables. Out of these 30, ten have sequential names - X1, X2,....X10. All these X  variables are characters. I wanted to concatenate all of them. So I could of course do

```
db1$new <- paste(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10)
```

But, this is not fun, and if I have a new file with different number of X variables, this code will not work. So, I need some method that concatenates using the variable name. I tried

```
zz1 <- paste(grep('^X',names(db1), value = TRUE))
zz2 <- paste("db1$",zz1,sep="",collapse = ",")
```

The second statement is to get the variable names seperated by commas. I then tried merging using

```
db1$new <- paste(db1$Terms,zz2,collapse = ","))
```

This did not work as R did not understand the zz2 were file names. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `do.call` with `paste0`, like this, Using the dataset like below(Using @MKR data):

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, X1 = c("a", "b"), X2 = c("a", "b"), 
        X3 = c("a", "b")), .Names = c("id", 
    "X1", "X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df$pastecol = do.call("paste0",df[,grep("^X\\d+$",names(df))])
```

**Output**:

```
#> df$pastecol = do.call("paste0",df[,grep("^X\\d+$",names(df))])
#> df
#  id X1 X2 X3 pastecol
#1  1  a  a  a      aaa
#2  2  b  b  b      bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be by using `select_` from `dplyr` and then `apply`.

```
#data
db1 <- data.frame(id = 1:2, x1 = c("a", "b"), x2 = c("a", "b"),
                  x3 = c("a", "b"))

library(tidyverse)

db1$new <- db1 %>% 
select_(.dots = grep("^x\\d+",names(db1), value = T)) %>%
apply(1,paste,collapse="") 

db1
# Result
#  id x1 x2 x3 new
#1  1  a  a  a aaa
#2  2  b  b  b bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

unite(db1, "var", starts_with("x"), sep = "")

#   var z1
# 1 aaa  a
# 2 bbb  b
```

This will `unite` any column that `starts_with` "x" and stores the result in a variable named `var`.

If the data is structured such that there are other variables starting with "x" that aren't of interest (e.g. "xvar") and should not be concatenated, then you can replace `starts_with` with `matches` and use regular expressions. Thank MKR for the suggestion:

```
unite(db1, "var", matches("^x\\d+"), sep = "")

#   var z1 xvar
# 1 aaa  a    a
# 2 bbb  b    b
```

Data:

```
db1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b"), 
                  x2 = c("a", "b"),
                  z1 = c("a", "b"),
                  x3 = c("a", "b"))
```

Comment: Good use of `starts_with` and `unitie`. I can see a scope of improvement. `starts_with` will consider all column like `xa`, `xname` etc. But perhaps OP intention is to consider `x1`, `x2` etc only.

Comment: Good point. In that case, we can replaced `starts_with` with `matches("x\\d+")` using you're regular expression.

Comment: Of course, I was updating it the second you mentioned it. Just got distracted when looking at regex.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be better to change `x\\d+` to `^x\\d+`? That way something like `lax2` wouldn't get picked up. Also noticed OP has this in his `grep` call.